# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Pin of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: arduino

I am relatively new to android programming and I have been facing this problem. I am currently working on Interfacing android with Arduino and controlling device with an app. I am facing a problem in this part of the Front End where I have switches which would send POST request with some string as parameter. But I keep getting this error. I did search the internet first for the answer but no one seems to have any problems related to throwing exceptions as " Value Pin of type". The code for the Front End java and PHP is posted below. Thank you for your help.

changeState.php

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    //initial query
    $query = "INSERT INTO status ( leaf_id, state ) VALUES ( :pinNumber, :pinState ) ";

    //Update query



    $stageOne = explode(',',$status);

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($stageOne);$i++) {
    $pinNumber=$pinState="0";
    $stageTwo = explode('-',$stageOne[$i]);
    $pinNumber = $stageTwo[0]; 
    $pinState = $stageTwo[1];
    echo "Pin number : ".$pinNumber."</br>";
    echo "Pin state : ".$pinState."</br>";

    //execute query
    $query_params = array(
        ':pinNumber' => $pinNumber,
        ':pinState' => $pinState    
    );
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute( $query_params );
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add post!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "State Change Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
?>
        <h1>Waiting for user Interation</h1> 
         <form action="changeState.php" method="post"> 
            Status:<br /> 
            <input type="text" name="status" placeholder="Change status" /> 
            <br /><br /> 

        </form> 

    <?php
}

?>
```

controlFrontEnd.java

```
package com.thulung.bathiama;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class controlFrontEnd extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    boolean outlet1_status = false;
    boolean outlet2_status = false;
    boolean outlet3_status = false;
    boolean outlet4_status = false;
    boolean outlet5_status = false;
    boolean outlet6_status = false;

    private ImageView outlet1;
    private ImageView outlet2;
    private ImageView outlet3;
    private ImageView outlet4;
    private ImageView outlet5;
    private ImageView outlet6;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    private static final String STATECHANGE_URL = "http://192.168.1.102/Test/BathiAma/bathiama/changeState.php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    String DebugOutletMessage = new String("Status Message");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buttons);

     outlet1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.outlet1);
     outlet2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.outlet2);
     outlet3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.outlet3);
     outlet4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.outlet4);
     outlet5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.outlet5);
     outlet6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.outlet6);   

    outlet1.setOnClickListener(this);
    outlet2.setOnClickListener(this);
    outlet3.setOnClickListener(this);
    outlet4.setOnClickListener(this);
    outlet5.setOnClickListener(this);
    outlet6.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.outlet1:
        if(!outlet1_status)
            outlet1.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);    
        else 
            outlet1.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);

        outlet1_status=!outlet1_status;
        break;
    case R.id.outlet2:
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Outlet 2 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(!outlet2_status)
            outlet2.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);    
        else 
            outlet2.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
        outlet2_status=!outlet2_status;
        break;
    case R.id.outlet3:
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Outlet 3 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(!outlet3_status)
            outlet3.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);    
        else 
            outlet3.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
        outlet3_status=!outlet3_status;

        break;
    case R.id.outlet4:
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Outlet 4 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(!outlet4_status)
            outlet4.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);    
        else 
            outlet4.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);

        outlet4_status=!outlet4_status;

        break;

    case R.id.outlet5:
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Outlet 5 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(!outlet5_status)
            outlet5.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);    
        else 
            outlet5.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
        outlet5_status=!outlet5_status;
        break;
    case R.id.outlet6:
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Outlet 6 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(!outlet6_status)
            outlet6.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);    
        else 
            outlet6.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
        outlet6_status=!outlet6_status;
        break;
    default:

        break;  
    }
     String state1 = booleanToString(outlet1_status);
     String state2 = booleanToString(outlet2_status);
     String state3 = booleanToString(outlet3_status);
     String state4 = booleanToString(outlet4_status);
     String state5 = booleanToString(outlet5_status);
     String state6 = booleanToString(outlet6_status);

     //building parameter to Send for storing in db
     String stateOfMachine = "2-"+state1+","+"3-"+state2+","+"4-"+state3+","+"5-"+state4+","+"6-"+state5+","+"7-"+state6;
     new changeSwitchState().execute(stateOfMachine);


    }

 class changeSwitchState extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(controlFrontEnd.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check for success tag
            int success;
            JSONObject json = null;
            String stateOfMachine = args[0];
            Log.d("to Parse - Control Front End",stateOfMachine);

            //Retrieving Saved Username Data:
            //SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(controlFrontEnd.this);
            //String post_username = sp.getString("username", "anon");


            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", stateOfMachine));
                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script 

                 json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        STATECHANGE_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Change Status attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Status Changed!", json.toString());    
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Status Change Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(controlFrontEnd.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

     public String booleanToString(boolean logic){
         if(logic)
         return "1";
         else
         return "0"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. The error was in the php data echo-ed. If you encounter such error, be sure that you are not sending rubbish i.e. plain text to receiver.